# Columns rename: switching between numbers and letters

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

My dataframe:

```
X   Y   123_Z   1234_Z  123_Z_R 1234_Z_R
.   .   .       .       .       .
.   .   .       .       .       .
```

I want to rename the columns in the data by switching the numbers and letters.

Expected result:

```
X   Y   Z_123   Z_1234  Z_R_123 Z_R_1234
.   .   .       .       .       .
.   .   .       .       .       .
```

Note: I have lots of columns without numbers and with numbers. So I'm trying to avoid to do it manually.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Maybe this works

```
df.columns = map(lambda s: '_'.join(s[1:] + [s[0]]) if  s[0].isdigit() else '_'.join(s), df.columns.str.split('_'))
```

---

```
Columns: ['X', 'Y', 'X_Y', 'Z_123', 'Z_1234', 'Z_R_123', 'Z_R_1234']
```

Answer (score 3):

#### `map` and `reversed`

```
df.columns = ['_'.join(reversed(x.split('_', 1))) for x in df.columns]
df

   X  Y Z_123 Z_1234 Z_R_123 Z_R_1234
0  .  .     .      .       .        .
1  .  .     .      .       .        .
```

---

#### `rename`

```
df.rename(columns=lambda x: '_'.join(reversed(x.split('_', 1))))

   X  Y Z_123 Z_1234 Z_R_123 Z_R_1234
0  .  .     .      .       .        .
1  .  .     .      .       .        .
```

---

## In Case You Need To Pay Close Attention To Numbers

Use `re` for a regex split

```
import re

#                                               regex lookbehind
#                                               to check if underscore
#                                               is preceded by a digit
#                                                        
df.rename(columns=lambda x: '_'.join(reversed(re.split('(?<=\d)_', x, 1))))

   X  Y Z_123 Z_1234 Z_R_123 Z_R_1234
0  .  .     .      .       .        .
1  .  .     .      .       .        .
```